# Need to merge 2 FFMPEG commands

Tags: ffmpeg

I currently use this command to merge the video, a watermark image and an audio track -

`ffmpeg -y -an -i L4472.mp4 -vn -i TTS-Audio-Music.mp4 -i IGR-Video-Service-75%.png -filter_complex "[0][2]overlay=10:10:format=yuv420" -c:v libx264 -crf 17 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy Z:\02Videos\Final\L4472.mp4`

The audio file is of 15 seconds, but some of the videos I have are just 5-6 seconds each, so I need to loop the videos in order to run the whole audio file. I tried to first only loop the videos using

`ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -i L4472.mp4 -t 15 -c copy Z:\02Videos\Final\L4472.mp4`

and then run the first code, but I always get an error, and the output file does not play.

I have had a similar issue earlier when I tried to add the watermark and audio with 2 separate commands. So I would like to have a single code to do all of this together.

Also, I would like to ensure that the original audio track in the video file is not used in the output. So please help me with a way to merge these 3 into 1 output using a single command:

1. Video (without the original audio), looped to 15 seconds
2. Watermark image
3. Audio track

You can download the 3 sample files I am using from this link - https://we.tl/t-HtyzDy7lAw

Thank you in advance for your time and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `-stream_loop -1` before `-i L4472.mp4`, and add `-shortest` before `-c:v`.

- `-stream_loop -1` applies infinite loop to the input that comes after the `-i`.
- `-shortest` finish encoding when the shortest input stream ends (the audio stream is going to be the shortest because the video duration is infinite).

---

Sample command:

`ffmpeg -y -an -stream_loop -1 -i L4472.mp4 -vn -i TTS-Audio-Music.mp4 -i IGR-Video-Service-75.png -filter_complex "[0][2]overlay=10:10:format=yuv420" -shortest -c:v libx264 -crf 17 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy Final_L4472.mp4`

Comment: Thank you Rotem, your suggestions are just superb, the original command was also made with your help only. I only made one change to your current suggestion, the ```-shortest``` command was making it loop till the end of the current video loop, meaning if the original video was 6 seconds, the output was 18 seconds, even though the audio stopped at 15 seconds. So I replaced it with ```-t 15``` and now the video ends at exactly at 15 seconds. I learnt a little more about this great software today, and I thank you for your help, I really REALLY appreciate it.

Comment: Interesting... Using FFmpeg 4.4.1-full_build-www.gyan.dev, and the input files from your link, the output length is 15.2 seconds (using `-shortest`).

Comment: Hi Rotem, I needed a small variation in this code which was finalized by your help -

ffmpeg -y -an -stream_loop -1 -i 29243.mp4 -vn -i TTS-Audio-Music.mp4 -i IGR-Logo-Video-Services.png -filter_complex "[0][2]overlay=10:10:format=yuv420" -t 15 -c:v libx264 -crf 17 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy Z:\02Videos\Final\29243.mp4

This time I have a new video of 10 seconds, and instead of looping the video, I want it to slow down so that it is 15 seconds (the length of my audio). I tried the setpts filter, but keep getting errors.

You may download the files here - https://we.tl/t-zrmRSNy32B

Comment: I recommend you to ask a new question (add a reference to this question), add the command you have tried, and post the error message. `setpts` works most of the time for [changing the speed](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20speed%20up%20/%20slow%20down%20a%20video). Try `"[0][2]overlay=10:10:format=yuv420,setpts=0.6667*PTS"`. I don't know how to slow down the audio.